# How each row and column is distributed in a Grid Layout?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to understand how each row/column of a `Grid Layout` is 'created/distributed'.

```
QtWidgetsApplication::QtWidgetsApplication(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    // Create the GridLayout
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;

    QPushButton* b1 = new QPushButton();
    b1->setGeometry(0, 0, 50, 40);
    b1->setText("B1");

    QPushButton* b2 = new QPushButton();
    b2->setGeometry(0, 0, 50, 40);
    b2->setText("B2");

    QPushButton* b3 = new QPushButton();
    b3->setGeometry(0, 0, 50, 40);
    b3->setText("B3");

    QPushButton* b4 = new QPushButton();
    b4->setGeometry(0, 0, 50, 40);
    b4->setText("B4");

    auto columns = layout->columnCount();
    auto rows = layout->rowCount();
    qDebug() << "nº of columns: " << columns << "\nnº of rows: " << rows << "\n";

    layout->addWidget(b1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    layout->addWidget(b2, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    layout->addWidget(b3, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    layout->addWidget(b4, 1, 0, 0, 1);

    // Set layout in QWidget
    QWidget *window = new QWidget();
    window->setLayout(layout);

    // Set QWidget as the central layout of the main window
    setCentralWidget(window);
    return;
}
```

The add widget function is:

`void addWidget(QWidget*, int row, int column, int rowSpan, int columnSpan, Qt::Alignment = Qt::Alignment());`

`qDebug()` printed the grid has 1 column and 1 row.

How the grid would be illustrated? This way?

[image]

The code above resulted in this window:

[image]

Comment: Your question is rather unclear.  Can you be more specific about exactly what you're trying to understand?  What would you expect to see if you specify (as you have) that a widget should have a row or column span of zero?  Don't you see any warning messages at the console?

Comment: Rowspan is how many rows widget is spanned across, default value is 1, I dont get the idea behind setting it to 0, you want widget to be hidden?

Comment: QGridLayout adds rows and columns as necessary when you add widgets to it, before you added any, it's one row one column.

Answer (score 0):

Rows and columns are arranged in a plain rectangular grid like this, nothing special. It's a 2x3 grid.

```
        col#0        col#1        col#2
row#0   cell         cell         cell
row#1   cell         cell         cell
```

Your code has errors specifying the `rowSpan` or `columnSpan` arguments to zeros. That will cause an undefined behavior, as your observation.